# How to increment a Couner column by 1 with each inserted row BUT per each guid

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

Apologies for the clumsy title feel free to suggest an improvement.

I have a table *Records* and there's a *UserId* column that refers to who's made the deposition. There's also *Counter* column which is *identity(1,1)* (it's important to keep in mind that it's not same one as the *Id* column that is the primary key).

The problem got obvious when we started depositing from different accounts, because before, the user could ask for record number 123 through 127, getting 5 amounts but now, their picks might be 123, 125, 126 or even worse - nothing at all.

The only option to handle it as far I can imagine to create a business logic layer that checks for the highest deposition counter for a user and adds the new record with that increased by one.

But it sure would be nice to have it automagically working. Something like *identity(1,1,guid)*. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only option to handle it as far I can imagine to create a business
>   logic layer that checks for the highest deposition counter for a user
>   and adds the new record with that increased by one.

Time to learn.

- Add the last given number to the account table.
- Use a trigger to assign higher numbers in the insert event of SQL Server.

Finished. This obviously assumes your relational database is used in a relational fashion so the records are related to a user table, not just holding a user id (which would be a terrible design).

If not, you can also maintain a table of all seen GUID's by means of said trigger.

Comment: "*...in the insert event...*"? Are you referring to the event of my, from my C# inserting something? Or is it a SQL-term alike with triggers? I've always been afraid of triggers so it's time to grow a pair, hehe.

Comment: No, i mean SQL Server triggers. If you do not really know anything about SQL Server you should not program it. Database servers have a lot of capabilities that those of us learning to use our tools know about. One of them is changing the data inserted by running a triggered script on the server.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain such a column, you would need a trigger.

You might consider calculating the value when you query the table:

```
select r.*, row_number() over (partition by guid order by id) as seqnum
from records r;
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. I forgot to mention that I'll be querying the table using EF so the number needs actually to be stored there upon inserting the row. +1 for a neat statement, though.

Comment: @KonradViltersten . . . You can use a view to calculate the number.  EF can access views.